# My Cloud account seems to be hacked. How to remove extra projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I haven't used Google Cloud in years and today I've logged in and I've found that there are several projects in https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/
and https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager?organizationId=0&authuser=0 that I didn't create.
I'm not the owner of those projects and I can't do anything with them.

What can I do to clean this up?
My GMail account is protected with 2FA, how did they managed to create these projects?

Any hint about where to look for help would be great as Google doesn't seem to care unless I pay for a support plan.

Comment: Most likely you do not have a problem. You can be a member of a project thru Google Groups and other methods. What are the Project IDs? To double-check, go to your Google Cloud Billing Account. There you can see the projects that you are responsible for. If the project is not listed there, then you are not paying for the project. If there is a project that you do not know about connected to your billing account, immediately contact Google Cloud Billing Support which is free.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley it seems that you're right. I asked for help in other places and someone working at Google noticed that there was a "git-for-windows@googlegroups.com" member in those projects and it seems that I joined that group some years ago to ask a question. I exited all the Google Groups yesterday and now there are no strange projects any longer.
If you post an answer I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you do not have a problem.

You can be a member of a project thru Google Groups and other methods.

To double-check, go to your Google Cloud Billing Account. There you can see the projects that you are responsible for. If the project is not listed there, then you are not paying for the project.

If there is a project that you do not know about connected to your billing account, immediately contact [Google Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) which is free.

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer. I hope that other people facing the same problem is able to find this question/answer to ease their minds and fix it by exiting from any Google Group.

Comment: Yesterday a project called `Hacked` and another one called `myiphoneapp` appeared in my console and I didn't have access to the delete button.  I saw they had some API usages and frantically started disabling the services it connects to. Then I found this answer, exited every group and the weird projects are gone. Sorry for the `Hacked` project's owner, I probably destroyed some of their settings.